# Execute commands on AccesKey pressed & release

Tags: c#, inheritance, mvvm

so i'm trying to execute a command when a user pressed the AccesKey and another command when the user releases the AccesKey.

i tryed working with a timer that executed a code after like 500 miliseconds but that didnt really worked out.

so far i have this:

```
public sealed class CustomButton : Button
{
 private bool _isPressed = false;

 protected override void OnAccessKey(AccessKeyEventArgs e)
  {
  if (!_isPressed)
   {
   //execute command when pressed

   _isPressed = true;
   }  
   //execute command when AccesKey released
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have writen is not WPF...

WPF is
In xaml file:

```
`<Button Name="btnWebBackward"  Width="24"  MouseDown="btnWebBackward_MouseDown" MouseUp="btnWebBackward_MouseUp"  ></Button>`
```

and
in code behind:

```
 private void btnWebBackward_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnWebBackward_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

As i can see, your approach of creating your own button have no sense..

Comment: thanks for the response, but im using the mvvm model thats why im not doing it in xaml. i will change the tag.